# Referencing Data from Data Relationship

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I am new to AmpScript and am trying to figure out how to reference data from 1 data extension with data in another data extension. I created a Data Relationship between the two but am having trouble pulling that data into an email.

Our 1st data extension includes `client_email_addr` (which is our primary key to email subscribers) and `home_studio1`.

The 2nd data extension includes `home_studio1` and `studio_url` with `home_studio1`set to the primary key.

I would like to reference the 2nd data extension `2017_Master Studio List` and when a customer's `home_studio1` matches that list, display the coinciding `studio_url` within and email.

I found the lookup function syntax `Lookup(1, 2, 3, 4)`, where I believe I would structure it as such:

```
%%=Lookup('2017_Master Studio List','studio_url','home_studio1',?)=%%
```

But I'm not sure what the #4 is in the syntax if I'm simply trying to find matching values. If I were to specifically list each location as that 4th value, I would have 100s of rows of AmpScript which seems to defeat the purpose.

Am I on the right track here?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Data Relationship won't help you in AMPScript.  Data Relationships are primarily for data filters.

I'd suggest using the [**lookupRows()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm) function.  Here's an example on how you might use it:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount
var @homeStudio
set @homeStudio = AttributeValue("home_studio1") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */

set @rows = LookupRows("2017_Master Studio List","home_studio1", @homeStudio)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

  var @studio_url
  set @row = row(@rows,1) /* get row #1 */
  set @studio_url = field(@row,"studio_url")

]%%

studio_url is %%=v(@studio_url)=%%

%%[ else ]%%

No studio found

%%[ endif ]%%
```

You retrieve the current subscriber's value for `home_studio1` and then use it to lookup rows in `2017_Master Studio List`.  The function returns a rowset and in this case, we only need the first match.  We then can retrieve the value for `studio_url` from the row-set and assign it to a new AMPScript variable.  Once you have the variable set, you can display it outside of the AMPScript block with `%%=v()=%%`.

There are some more [**lookup examples here**](https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/).

Comment: Thanks Adam! What do you mean by setting a new AMPScript Variable? How do I do that?

Comment: You initialize a variable with `var` and set it with `set`.